# React mixin to declaratively get Bacon.js event steams

Tags: javascript, react.js, bacon.js, frp

I wrote a mixin to declaratively get a Bacon.js event stream.  So instead of `onChange={this.handleChange}`, you can do `changeStream={this.handleStream}`, and `this.handleStream` will be passed an `onChange` Bacon.js event stream.  My big concern is that I have to override `React.createElement` in order to make it work.  I'm wondering how hacky/dangerous this is.

```
function pushToStream(handlerFn, event) {
   event.persist();
   handlerFn.__stream.push(event);
 }

 function getEventFromStreamName(prop) {
   var match = prop.match(/(\w+)Stream$/);
   if (!match || !match[1]) return null;
   return 'on' + capitalize(match[1]);
 }

 function capitalize(s) {
   return s && s[0].toUpperCase() + s.slice(1);
 }

 var BaconMixin = {
   componentWillMount: function() {
     if (React.createElement.__custom) return;

     var _createElement = React.createElement;
     React.createElement = function(el, props) {
       Object.keys(props || {}).forEach(function(prop) {
         var eventName = getEventFromStreamName(prop);
         if (!eventName) return;

         var handlerFn = props[prop];
         var context = handlerFn.__reactBoundContext;

         handlerFn.__stream = handlerFn.__stream || new Bacon.Bus();
         handlerFn.__pushFn = handlerFn.__pushFn || pushToStream.bind(null, handlerFn);

         props[eventName] = handlerFn.__pushFn;
       });

       return _createElement.apply(this, arguments);
     }

     React.createElement.__custom = true;

     return {};
   },
   componentDidMount: function() {
     var self = this;
     Object.keys(this).forEach(function(prop) {
       if (self[prop] && self[prop].__stream) {
         self[prop](self[prop].__stream);
       }
     });
   },
   componentWillUnmount: function() {
     var self = this;
     Object.keys(this).forEach(function(prop) {
       if (self[prop] && self[prop].__stream) {
         self[prop].__stream.end();
       }
     });
   }
 }

 /* Usage:

 var UsernameInput = React.createClass({

   mixins: [BaconMixin],

   searchAvailability: function(eventStream) {
    // eventStream is a Bacon.Bus instance
     eventStream
       .debounce(500)
       .map('.target.value')
       .makeAjaxRequest
       .onValue(function(isAvailable) {
         // update state
       }.bind(this));
   },

   render: function() {
     return (
       <div>
         <label htmlFor="username">Username:</label>
         <input type="text" name="username" keyUpStream={this.searchAvailability} />
       </div>
     );
   }
 });

 React.render(<UsernameInput />, document.body);

*/
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. I hope you get some great answers!